# Update Database tables with values input by user in CodeIgniter using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model, controller

I'm trying to update one of my user tables in the Database with values taken from the the user. But for some reason it's not updating anything.

**HTML Form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method = "post">
<fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>User Details</legend>

    <div>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="something" class="form-control input-md">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="dob" name="dob" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Multiple Radios -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Male</option>
                <option value="2">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="degree">Degree</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="degree" name="degree" type="text" placeholder="degree" class="form-control input-md">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="specialization">Specialization</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="specialization" name="specialization" type="text" placeholder="specialization" class="form-control input-md">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="year">Degree Year</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="semester">Semester</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select id="semester" name="semester" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- File Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Upload Profile Picture</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="filebutton" name="filebutton" class="input-file" type="file">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url("/index.php/studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails"); ?>" >
                <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

**studentDashboardController**

```
public function  saveUserDetails()
{
     $this->load->model('userModel');
     if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']))
     {
          $username = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['username']);
     }
     $user = $this-> userModel-> getUserUid($username); //Gets the uid of the current user
     $this->userModel->saveUserDetails($user);
     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Successfully Inserted Data</div>');
     $this->load->view('studentDashboard/common',$data);
     redirect(base_url('index.php/studentDashboard/editProfile',$data1));
}
```

**userModel**

```
public function saveUserDetails($uid)
{
    $data = array(
         'name' => $this->input->post('name')
    );
    $this->db->where("uid",$uid);
    $this->db->update("sysuser",$data);
}
```

The sysuser has the uid and name fields.I' not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: @questiontable please post if you got any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont send your post data to controller. Change `$this->userModel->saveUserDetails($user);` as

```
 $this->userModel->saveUserDetails($user,$this->input->post('name'));
```

Now Model should be like

```
public function saveUserDetails($uid,$name)
{
    $data = array(
         'name' => $name
    );
    $this->db->where("uid",$uid);
    $this->db->update("sysuser",$data);
}
```

and make sure you have set correctly form action like

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails');?>">
```

Comment: I would like to know, if I had to insert multiple values gathered from the user into two different tables how can I do that?

Comment: couldn't understand.

Comment: In the question that I've asked above, I'm only updating the `name` onto the `sysuser` database table that I have. Now I need to insert a few other details such as the details requested in the form above, into the `studentprofile` table that I have while updating the name itself. How can I send all the user input to the model's method in order to update the `sysuser` table and insert the other user inputs into the `studentprofile` table?

Comment: send data like `$this->userModel->saveUserDetails($user,$this->input->post());` and grab like `public function saveUserDetails($uid,$post){$name = $post['name'];$another = $post['another']}`